# Using .htaccess to redirect /sitemap.xml to /index.php/sitemap/

Tags: .htaccess, codeigniter, mod-rewrite

I'm using codeigniter to generate a page that contains XML data. The URL of the file is located at /index.php/sitemap, but I want the URL to be accessed via /sitemap.xml

My `.htaccess` file is already modified to allow users to access URLs without entering /index.php/ before URLs. This is the `.htacess` file I'm using:

```
RewriteEngine On

RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} -s [OR]
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} -l [OR]
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} -d
RewriteRule ^.*$ - [NC,L]
RewriteRule ^.*$ index.php [NC,L]

RewriteRule ^sitemap\.xml$ index.php/sitemap [L]
```

Everything is working fine, except the redirection of the sitemap.xml file. I'm on a windows machine running XAMPP

What am I doing wrong?

Comment: You may want to move the xml line above the index rule since that one will match first.

Comment: I have found codeigniters URL routing method to work, but for future reference putting this rule at the top gave me a 404 error.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Skip the .htaccess modifications and use a normal route instead.

```
$route['sitemap\.xml'] = 'sitemap';
```

Comment: Thank you, this worked. I don't know why I didn't think of using codeigniters URL routing.

Answer (score 0):

```
RewriteRule ^.*sitemap\.xml$ index.php/sitemap [L]
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ /index.php/$1 [L]
```

You are matching before you reach the sitemap check so it always redirected to `index.php`.

This is the example from the [user guide](http://ellislab.com/codeigniter/user-guide/general/urls.html):

```
RewriteEngine on
RewriteCond $1 !^(index\.php|images|robots\.txt)
RewriteRule ^.*/(.*)$ /index.php/$1 [L]
```

You can just shove the check for sitemap in there before the standard index.php rewrite

```
RewriteEngine on
RewriteCond $1 !^(index\.php|images|robots\.txt)
RewriteRule ^.*/sitemap\.xml$ index.php/sitemap [L]
RewriteRule ^.*/(.*)$ /index.php/$1 [L]
```

Comment: For some reason using the example from the user guide gives me 500 server error on my local host so I am forced to use the other `.htaccess` file I found on the codeigniter forums

Comment: Ok so just put the XML rewrite before the index.php rewrite

Comment: I have found codeigniters URL routing method to work, but for future reference putting this rule at the top gave me a 404 error.

Comment: yup; was missing a forward slash. `RewriteRule ^.*/(.*)$ /index.php/$1 [L]`

Answer (score 0):

The order of the rules is important. The rules are processed in the order they are written. The pattern `.*` matches everything and therefore the rule

```
RewriteRule ^.*$ index.php [NC,L]
```

rewrites all requests before they can reach the last rule.

When you put the `sitemap.xml` rule at the top, it will work as expected.

Comment: I have found codeigniters URL routing method to work, but for future reference putting this rule at the top gave me a 404 error.